# How to rename "Title" column in "Item" content type

Tags: sharepoint

I wrongly renamed the 'Title' to 'First Name' in the Item content type.  Now sharepoint won't allow me to rename 'First Name' back to 'title'.  Now in my site all Title columns show up as 'First Name'.

Can anyone please help to rename 'First name' back to 'Title'?

Comment: This google search seems to give possible solutions: http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&source=hp&q=sharepoint+%2B+rename+column&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=6b894f18c776bed3

Comment: u r not txting here. pls spl out wrds.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest it to use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com):

- Go to the right site collection
- Go to the right site
- Open Fields
- Find the column and rename the Title property
- Save

Answer (score 2):

Once you change the name from Title to something else, you are stuck - you can never call it Title again since it is a reserved name by SharPoint.

Rename the Title to "Item" or "Item Title" instead - this is usually a suitable fix (I've been through this a few times when my Content Editors go a little nuts)

Once you have the Content Type working with a better generic title field, like "Item" you can go into each of the lists and change the Title field to something more useful locally (NOT in the content types). For instance in a Contacts list - the title would probably be "Last Name" - or in a custom product list the title could be "Product"