# the-display-name-of-the-title-column-in-a-content type has changed in all the lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The problem created when we tried do create a new content type for a list. We went to site settings/Content types.

Created the custom content type and clicks the title column Change the name to something nice. In that case what we were changing is the display name of the Title Site Column.

And once we discovered that it changed the title column in all lists, we tried to change it back, but this is prevented by the clever SharePoint UI because Title is a reserved name. Will deleting the custom content type will help restore the names?

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the name from Title to something else, you are stuck - you can never call it Title again since it is a reserved name by SharPoint.

There may be two fixes but both are manual fixes. 
Please see the link given below.

[How to rename "Title" column in "Item" content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119575/how-to-rename-title-column-in-item-content-type)